# Concat paginated response using Rxjs in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I am calling an external API from an angular2 app, which provides data in paginated form. The response looks like this

```
{
   next: "next_url",
   results: []
}
```

Can I use Rxjs or inbuilt Http class of Angular2, which returns an observable, to concat the results from next url, till

```
{
   next: null,
   results: []
}
```

I feel I need to user concatMap operator, but I have not figured out the syntax as I am new to Reactive Extentions.

Comment: ConcatMap sounds right. What have you tried?

Comment: Is this code in a service?  If so, are components subscribing to the http.get() result?  I ask because you might be able to simply push the new data onto your existing array:  `this.someComponentArray.push(...newData);`

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards I did try concatMap but I am not very sure about the syntax.
@MarkRajcok Yes. I am calling a function from the service which return an observable (http.get in this case probably!). As `this.someComponentArray.push(...newData);` needs to be implemented in the component I, instead I want the service the return an observable the does that for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h2>Results: {{out | async | json}}</h2>`,
})
export class App {
  constructor() { 
    this.out = this.getAllResults();
  }

  getAllResults(startIdx = 0) {
    return this.getData(startIdx)
      .concatMap(data => {
        if (data.next) {
          return this.getAllResults(data.next)
            .map(resultsToJoin => [...data.results, ...resultsToJoin]);
        } else {
          return Observable.of(data.results);
        }
      });
  }

  // pretend this is our http call 
  getData(idx : number) {
    const data = [{
        next: 1,
        results: [1, 2]
      }, {
        next: 2,
        results: [3, 4]
      }, {
        next: null,
        results: [5, 6]
    }];

    return Observable.of(data[idx]);
  } 
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7r4TaW

Comment: @Lodewojik Thanks.. It worked flawless..
One change I tried was only importing Observer `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";`. working in latest beta

Comment: what if you want to return the next value too

Answer (score 4):

Just of sake of an alternative solution this one also works

```
getAllResults(startIdx = 0) {
  return this.getData(startIdx)
    .expand(data => {
      return data.next ? this.getData(data.next) : Observable.empty()
    }).scan((acc, data) => {
      return [...acc, ...data.results]
    }, []);

}
```

`expand` operator recursively call the inner observable. Without `scan` operator, it would keep emitting data of each page. Use `scan` to reduce the data of each page into single array of results.

Note: This is not exactly the solution I was looking for. Because it emits each page results as array, and not just the final array. But was interesting to discover these useful operators.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vrZEywkeys6sa5Nsccbg?p=preview